# xpath take all the text, not just the first line

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I have this html

```
    <td colspan="2" align="justify" class="inPage">
                <p>
                    2 bedroom + maids +balcony in Tiara Residence - Diamond type
                    <br>1700 sq.ft, furnished with kitchen equipment
                    <br>Sea view/ Atlantis view
                    <br>Selling Price: 4 million
                </p>
    </td>
```

My xpath is:

```
normalize-space(.//div[@class='section']/table/tr[7]/td/p/text())
```

The result is just `2 bedroom + maids +balcony in Tiara Residence - Diamond type`

I need the other text inside the `p` tag.

#### I am using scrapy 0.20 with python 0.27

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
normalize-space(.//div[@class='section']/table/tr[7]/td/p)
```

but this concatenate al text nodes, without any newline characters.

`normalize-space()`, as with other XPath string functions that expect a string argument, will convert the input node `p` to it's `string-value`. Quoting [XPath 1.0 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value):

> For every type of node, there is a way of determining a string-value for a node of that type. For some types of node, the string-value is part of the node; for other types of node, the string-value is computed from the string-value of descendant nodes